# Weinberg gravitation variational principle in free falling bodies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, variational-principle, geodesics, variational-calculus

In weinberg's gravitation and cosmology in page 77 appears this

[image: Weinberg's page]

[image: Christoffel symbols]

I can't see why the equation and the symmetry of Christoffel symbols and equation 3.3.5 makes that equation 3.3.10 appears
I ask my teacher for a similar proof with euler-lagrange equations, but he insist that Is only with the identity 3.3.5 AND playing with the index

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137422/2451 and links therein.